# Как стартовать скрипт расширения google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

Написал расширение, которое выбирает ссылки на странице, но проблема в том, что оно работает сразу же.

Вопрос такой: можно ли сделать, что бы оно искало ссылки когда я нажму на кнопку в `popup.html`?

Файл: contentscript.js

```
$(function(){

    $('a').each(function() {
       var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
       if (!a.test(this.href)) {
          // тут делаем что-то
       }
    });

})
```

Comment: В вопрос стоит добавить HTML код кнопки и ссылок из _popup.html_

Comment: Так у вас код выполняется по готовности DOM ($(function() { ... }()).
Нужно привязку к кнопке сделать, например:
$(function() {
  $('#button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ваш код
  });
});

Comment: @ikenfin так вот для того, чтобы правильно доработать код, нужно увидеть HTML. `#button`, конечно, схематично понятно, но всё же.

Comment: Этот код работает только с открытой в браузере страницей.

Comment: Так у этой волшебной кнопки есть уникальный идентификатор, чтобы повесить на неё обработчик нажатия?

Comment: Есть, и подключить нажатие могу, но как мне запустить именно этот файл contentscript.js ?

Comment: Перезадал вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430311/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-google-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8