# Как запустить скрипт по нажатию на кнопку в Google-приложении?

Tags: jquery, json, google-apps-script

Нужен знаток, который работал с Google-приложениями.

Вопрос: как запустить скрипт при нажатии на кнопку с `id` **start**?

Часть файла **manifest.json**

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
      "http://*/",
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/",
      "https://*/*"
       ],
    "js": [
        "jquery-1.11.3.min.js",
        "contentscript.js"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_end"
    }
],
```

Часть файла **popup.html**

```
<div id="start">Показать</div>
```

**contentscript.js**

```
$(function(){  
    $('a').each(function() {
       var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
       if (!a.test(this.href)) {
          $(this).css({
            "backgroundColor" : "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.27)",
            "padding" : "3px",
            "border" : "1px #f00 dashed",
            "opacity" : "1 !important",
            "display" : "inline-block !important"
          });
       }
    });  
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так.

Создать файл **background.js**

Обновить **manifest.json**, добавить следующие поля:

```
"permissions": [
      "activeTab"
    ]
"background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
```

содержание **background.js**

```
console.log('start');
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(req, sender, sendResp){
    if(req.message == "click"){
        console.log('click');
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "contentscript.js"});
        })
      }
   })
```

в **popup.js** добавить скрипт. Но не в **popup.html**! Там нельзя выполнять inline код. Затем добавить popup.js в popup.html

```
$('#start').onclick(function(){
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({message:'click'});
})
```

Comment: Сделал, а что писать в background.js ?

Comment: Не работает никак

Comment: Обновил background.js. Покажите, что выводится в консоли background после нажатия на кнопку.

Comment: Ничего не выводится

Comment: Как тут картинку вставить ?http://img.donnet.ru/preview/2015/06/16/5b00d7a.png

Comment: а вы из manifest.json убрали запуск contentscript.js? Обновлены permissions в manifest.

Comment: Да, вот   "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
      "http://*/",
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/",
      "https://*/*"
       ],
    "js": [
        "jquery-1.11.3.min.js"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}

Comment: и вывод такой-же, как на картинке img.donnet.ru/preview/2015/06/16/5b00d7a.png ?

Comment: Нет, сейчас вообще ничего не показывается. Можно в скайпе пообщаться? мой: kylaksizov